# How to pause execution and wait-for-client to attach with debugpy only on hitting an exception, not before that?

Tags: python, debugpy

debugpy usually pauses the execution from the begining and waits for client to attach. I want it to do that only and if it hits an exception, otherwise continue the execution.

I'm trying from command line:

python3 -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.2:2345 --wait-for-client example.py

Tried changing excepthook but that doesn't seem to work.